# Phonegap - Using it on a Website

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a small app mainly for self education purposes and I've decided to code the app in HTML / JS and use phonegap to convert it to a "native" app.

This is all working perfectly fine and I've successfully installed a HelloWorld app on my phone.

Besides as a native app I also want to make my project available on the internet using a browser. So that my users can either visit the url in their browser or download and install the app.

Therefore my question:

Is it possible to use Phonegap and its API online on a standard website? Meaning that I can use phonegaps functions to access the geolocation for example.

Otherwise I would have to change my javascript code and not use phonegap on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't believe that is going to work. What you could try instead is to wrap any calls that you make to phonegap with a check to see if you are on a phone or in a browser and switch based on that. This will force you to decouple your code from phonegap & create good boundaries.

I used this, which isn't perfect (especially if a users vists your site in their mobile browser), but it's a start:

```
  //jquery - for working in browser
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
      console.log("we are in a browser");
    }
  });

  //phonegap - for working in app
  function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("we are an app");
  }

  function onBodyLoad() {   
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }
```

Comment: I second this feedback. I've actually done this exact thing.  I created a "IsPhoneGapAvailable()" function I can call whenever I want to leverage something that is PhoneGap specific.  If the method returns false, then I know I'm on a web browser and I have to operate appropriately.  (i.e no camera, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The PhoneGap/Cordova API ties in with the functionality available on the device and therefore is not available via a "normal" website.

However, with the example you used, Geolocation is **NOT** PhoneGap/Cordova specific, it's a W3C specification and available on most modern browsers, so you can use that one.